# Is there a way to combine two conditions with and in SSRS Color Expression?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am attempting to have the text color change font based on these two expressions. Currently, I have the following for my expression:

I have googled how to have multiple conditions in an IIF statement, but I continue to come up with nested iif statements, which is not what I want.

```
=iif(fields!EffectiveDate.Value < Today() && fields!CertificationStatus.Vaule = "In Process", "Red", "Black")
```

I would like my in process certs that are past due to show red on the report to alert people to an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change && to And:

```
=iif(fields!EffectiveDate.Value < Today() And fields!CertificationStatus.Vaule = "In Process", "Red", "Black")
```